# How do I record streams in chunks on Flash Media Server

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, flash-media-server

I want to record a stream which is published with Flash Live Encoder to FMS 3.5, but split the recording in files with predefined length. For example if a stream 'webcam' is published I want to record it in chunks of 10 minutes: 'webcam1.flv',  'webcam2.flv' ...
From what I can tell there's no facility to work with timers. The only solution I could think of was using stream.record() with a time limit parameter but that seems like a hack because it triggers NetStream.Record.DiskQuotaExceeded on the stream when the recordin should stop and start recording another chunk.
Has anyone done something similar?

Answer (score 1):

On the server side why not just republish and record the stream with some timestamped name.  Then run a timer that fires every ten minutes (or whatever) which stops the recording of that stream, and creates a new server side stream playing the client stream.

Something along the lines of:

```
setInterval("setNewStream", 600000);

function setNewStream() {
var now = new Date();
serverStream.record(false);
var filename = "recording-"+ now.getHours() + "-" + now.getMinutes();
serverStream = Stream.get(filename);
serverStream.play("clientStream");
serverStream.record();
}
```